# Will an existing non-expiring token continue to work?

Tags: dropbox

In the Dropbox file API, one had the option to create a non-expiring access token. Dropbox has communicated that this option will be removed on 2021-09-30.

Will the non-expiring token that I already created continue to work, and for how long?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creation of new long-lived (non-expiring) Dropbox access tokens is now considered deprecated, but we don't currently have a plan to disable existing long-lived access tokens. (If that changes, we will of course announce that ahead of time.) That being the case, you can continue using existing long-lived access token(s). Note though that after the change you won't be able to create new long-lived access tokens.